# Paging out ROM after boot up

Tags: logic-gates, ram, rom

Building a Z80 computer, would like to boot CP/M from ROM and switch the ROM off after initial boot to make whole 64k RAM available for the CPU.

Solution I've got so far is using a flip-flop to disable ROM (and enable RAM) when a specific address range (0x8000-0xBFFF - i.e. A15=1, A14=0) appears on the bus. CP/M code starts from 0xDC00 so no issues with this approach as far as I can see.

Upon a reset, ROM and RAM2 becomes active, and once the switch occurs RAM1 and RAM2 stays active until the next reset.

1 - I tried to go through every case and it seems to be correct, but do you see any issues with this design?

2 - Can you sport any further simplifications? I feel like I used too many NAND gates :)

[image]

Note: This is a follow up to [a question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18407/z80-best-way-to-page-out-eeprom) on [RC.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), as it was mentioned there, that SE.EE would be more relevant. This solution is partly based on [recommendations](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18411/6659) given previously.

EDIT: Revised version to incorporate MREQ:

[image]

Comment: Hey, are you sure the CPU doesn't leave address lines floating to 3rd state in any phase?  Floating lines can catch noise and trig your system prematurely. You should allow the triggering only in something which could be called valid address state. Or at least have pull-up resistor in A14.

Comment: *For the members on both forums* - what does this mean?

Comment: @user287001, very good point thank you ! But now you made me worried about the refresh addressing :( As this would be a Z80 !

Comment: @Andyaka, I mean people reading both SE Retro Computing and SE.EE.

Comment: Refresh only scans between 0 an 128 so doesn't seem to be a blocker.

Comment: Following what was outlined on SE.RC, you need to include /MREQ, /M1 in your address line gating. No time at all to write an answer but you're looking for:  (a) /RAMCS gated with /MREQ;  (b) /ROMCS gated with /MREQ;  (c) writes always go to RAM;  (d) all reads are RAM when DFF=stateb, are EPROM (A15=0) or RAM (A15=1) when DFF=statea;  (e) on reset DFF=statea, on /M1=0 and A15=1 then DFF=stateb. Wish I had time to answer, work far far too busy.

Comment: If you use one bit of an I/O port (just a register cleared by Reset) you can page the ROM into that area with an I/O instruction. That (a) allows you to access the ROM facilities during runtime (by calling from code located somewhere else in memory space!) and (b) allows other bits in the register to swap RAM1 (or RAM3 .. RAM8)  into that space instead.

Comment: Leaving out READ/WRITE in decoding means that the decoding is now incomplete. Like TonyM said, MREQ will do it, as it activates during both. Keep in mind, its an x80 CPU, not a 65xx. Where 65xx CPUs have only one type of byus cycles, memory access, the Z80 has several bus cycles types: Internal, Refresh, I/O and Memory (the later split into opcode and data access). You got to make sure that above RAM/ROM only reacts during memory cycles and stay dormant all other times.

Comment: [A little hint for schematic drawing: Don't draw connections all around the whole page and coming in 'backwards' like done here done for /A15. It makes reading quite hard]

Comment: @BrianDrummond The idea was to save on I/O address decoding but as well to make the circuitry complete invisible after bootstrap. That way no OS or application has to take any care for a reserved port(bit) all 64KiB of memory as well as all I/O space is 100% free to use. Including use for any (more or less) sophisticated banking scheme.

Comment: So if I make IC1D and IC5A 3 input NAND gates and add MREQ to them it will be quite complete ? I will need two ICs to implement this regardless, so the second one can be a 3 input one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below circuit shows how it can be done. The principle is taken from the Z80 Second Processor for the BBC Micro and I'm sure the idea was around long before then, these things usually are.

The Z80 will use two address maps: a start-up map with the ROM available (ALLRAM is LOW) and the operating map with no ROM, just RAM (ALLRAM is HIGH).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLyLJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The start-up address map is:

```
ADDRESS RANGE    READ                 WRITE
0000..3FFFh      ROM image (16 KB)    RAM Low (first  16 KB)
4000..7FFFh      ROM image (16 KB)    RAM Low (second 16 KB)
8000..FFFFh      RAM High  (32 KB)    RAM High
```

Note that the ROM image appears twice. This harmlessly simplifies the address decoding. All writes in the 64 KB map go to the 64 KB RAM, so the RAM can be initialised easily.

The operating address map is:

```
ADDRESS RANGE    READ AND WRITE
0000..3FFFh      RAM Low  (32 KB)
8000..FFFFh      RAM High (32 KB)
```

The start-up address map is in use until the first instruction fetch from the upper 32 KB, which is always RAM.

After reset, the Z80 will execute from ROM address 0000h. Its ROM software can then follow the following example steps to get into the operating mode and be running CP/M:

```
Initialise the RAM with CP/M, copied from the ROM or wherever.
Store a 3-byte 'JP startCPM' instruction at 8000..8002h.
Do anything else the ROM needs to, before it vanishes until the next /RESET.
Execute a 'JP 8000h' instruction from ROM.
```

At the start of the JP instruction byte fetch cycle from 8000h, the D-type Flip-Flop (DFF) output ALLRAM will be preset to HIGH. ALLRAM will stay HIGH until the next /RESET.

This circuit uses OR and NOR logic gates, to illustrate the mechanisms used. It may well be possible to optimise it into fewer gates. When building one for real, though, you could look at using a CPLD instead (5 V-tolerant or 3V3, depending on your Z80 and memories) such as an XC9500XL part. A CPLD would be cheap and mop up the gates but it just depends what suits you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TonyM. Is this the case that DFFs CLK stays high until an instruction read from >8000, goes low during the read and next rising clock makes the FF flip ? Is there a reason this is done through CLK input ? My intuition would be connecting that /M1+/A15 OR gate output to /PRE of the FF directly.

Comment: @Charles, using /PRE would change ALLRAM during the JP op-code fetch. ALLRAM changing then has no effect, as RAM High is being accessed, not ROM or RAM Low. But the DFF can be set by /PRE or CLK so, given a free and equal choice between the two, it is better design behaviour to change ALLRAM at the end of the op-code read. Incidentally, don't go on instinct - assess all possible consequences and pick the simplest and most advantageous one. If the effect on the design is nothing, pick the one it would be better for people duplicate in other designs, as that often ends up happening in pro' eng'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes perfect sense.

Comment: Build this one, seems like I've got a timing issue. After the first write at 8000h, while moving onto next instruction it seems like M1 goes low while 8000h still on the address bus causing flip flop to trigger. I wonder if there was something additional on Z80 Second Processor to handle this ? Or I might be doing something wrong. Any ideas by any chance ?

Comment: To test changed M1 with RD as RD goes low after PC is put on the bus, it works naturally making the RAM write-only until the switch over.

Comment: @Charles, fixed - the circuit didn't include /MREQ and now goes off the start of the opcode memory read, not the end. Checked against Z80 datasheet and should work fine now. I appreciate you used /RD gating to test only but that stops all RAM reads so you'd have no stack. Thanks.